# How to install Greenplum Database in Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon 64-bit

Tags: linux, installation, package, greenplum

To install greenplum, I am following below steps:

[reference link](https://greenplum.org/install-greenplum-oss-on-ubuntu/)

```
sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common <br>
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:greenplum/db <br>
sudo apt-get update <br>
```

when we do

```
sudo apt-get update </b> we are getting following errors:
```

> Ign http://extra.linuxmint.com rebecca/main Translation-en_IN
>   Ign http://extra.linuxmint.com rebecca/main Translation-en
>   Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_IN
>   Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_IN
>   Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_IN
>   Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_IN
>   Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources
>   404  Not Found Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
>   404  Not Found Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages 
>   404  Not Found Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main
>   Translation-en_IN                      Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net
>   trusty/main Translation-en                         Ign
>   http://packages.linuxmint.com rebecca/import Translation-en_IN
>   Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com rebecca/import Translation-en
>   Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com rebecca/main Translation-en_IN
>   Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com rebecca/main Translation-en
>   Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com rebecca/upstream Translation-en_IN
>   Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com rebecca/upstream Translation-en
>   W: Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/greenplum/db/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources
>   404  Not Found W: Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/greenplum/db/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages
>   404  Not Found W: Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/greenplum/db/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages
>   404  Not Found E: Some index files failed to download. They have been
>   ignored, or old ones used instead.

It looks like the required package for greenplum to install are not available 
on linux mint.

Is there is any way to install greenplum on linux mint?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Trusty is Ubuntu 14.04. That's even before Greenplum Database was made Open Source.

Packages are available for Xenial, it looks like:

http://ppa.launchpad.net/greenplum/db/ubuntu/dists/

Comment: I am trying this on linux mint 17.1 Cinnamon 64-bit. so I need ppa for that.